# GA send event, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

Innit GA

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-6']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Track event

```
ga('send', {
              'hitType': 'event',
              'eventCategory': 'Customer',
              'eventAction': 'Registration',
              'eventLabel': 'Popup',
              'eventValue': 0.99
            });
```

But this allways return undefined, And I added the 'Registration' event (with that category, label and value) in conversions, at google analytics site,

Any idea why this could happen?

Of course it isn't tracked..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing old-style classic syntax (using the _gaq array) and Universal Analytics, so your ga object is not set up correctly (the tracker id from _gaq will not be used in the ga object and hence no tracker is created).

Your code should look something like this:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('send', {
              'hitType': 'event',
              'eventCategory': 'Customer',
              'eventAction': 'Registration',
              'eventLabel': 'Popup',
              'eventValue': 1
            });
```

Comment: I tried, but same.. undefined.., any other tought? thanks!

Comment: If you are  talking about the js console in the browser, that will return undefined even if the code works. Look in the realtime reports to see if the events show up.

Comment: Another problem I've just noticed is that evenValue does not accept floats - has to be an integer, or not set at all. Try and replace 0.99 with 1.

Answer (score 0):

@Eike Pierstorff is actually right, but there is a thing:

Option №1

https://groups.google.com/g/google-analytics-analyticsjs/c/mayu2cf1d0k?pli=1 - Thanks to Brad Townsend.

To be sure, that everything works fine in the browser console (I tested only Google Chrome), use Google Analytics Debugger Plugin, then go to Console, you will start seeing things like that:
"Executing/Running Google Analytics commands."

Try to send an event:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', {
              'hitType': 'event',
              'eventCategory': 'Test',
              'eventAction': 'Defined',
            });
```

For your every first event, you **must** write the first command:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

Or it will log that *target* is undefined.

Option №2:

Also, if you are using GTM and just want to use "ga('send')" like old times, you need to specify in UA-tag Tracker Name to blank:

Go to GTM, find your UA-tag -> Advanced Configuration -> Set Tracker Name ("True") -> leave the field "Tracker Name" blank.

[image: Google Analytics Tag]